# find a positive continuous function with a finite area : $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ , but the $f(x)\rightarrow$ doesn't exist.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

find a positive **continuous** function with a finite area : $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ , but the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to infinity doesn't exist.

I tried finding such a function but I failed .

Comment: Welcome to MSE, remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint - try looking at a function who's graph looks like a sequence of [triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) who's base gets smaller and smaller, so that the sum of areas of the triangles is finite, but the limit of $f$ does not exist.

If you want your function to be strictly positive, then you can add to it a positive factor which decays to 0 (like a decaying exponential).